# Can Application, Downloads and Document icons on the Dock be configured to just open finder?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, finder

Whenever you click on either Application, Downloads or Document icons on the Dock, you get this hard to read popup.

Is there any way to configure these buttons to open the appropriate folders in the Finder?

Answer (score 1):

Press 'command' button when you click on an icon. It opens a finder window with path to the application or document.

```
command + mouse_click
```